# Prompt user when cell is changed

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I'm very new to creating macros and programming in general.  I have a worksheet of 38 tabs.  31 tabs are for the days of the month.  I would like to create a macro that will prompt users with a warning message any time "MCO" is selected in column N for each of these 31 tabs.  Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: What does "anytime MCO is selected" mean?  What is MCO and what does it mean to select it?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, using a workbook level SheetSelectionChange event.  In the ThisWorkbook module in your VBA project paste the following code:

```
Option Compare Text
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim SelectedCellsInColN As Range
    ' Make a range of the cells in Target range that intersect with the cells in the N   column
    Set SelectedCellsInColN = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("N1:N" & CStr(Target.Parent.Rows.Count)))

    If Not SelectedCellsInColN Is Nothing Then
        ' The user has selected a cell in column N
        Dim CurrCell As Range
        For Each CurrCell In SelectedCellsInColN
            ' If the cell's value contains mco (in any case) then prompt the user with a messagebox
            If CurrCell.Value Like "*MCO*" Then
                MsgBox "You've selected MCO"
                ' Exit the sub so we don't keep bugging the user about it...
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next CurrCell
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically what the code does is look at the Target range to see if any cells in the N column are selected, and then loops through any of those cells in column N that are selected to see if their value contains MCO (you can get rid of the stars if you only want a prompt when the cell contains just "MCO"), and if so prompts the user and exits out.

Hope that helps.

-Jon

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a macro solution or a vba solution. The two are different.  For the macro run through the steps using the macro recoder, for a VBA solution start with Jon's answer